# Delete column with certain letter in first row

Tags: r

Suppose I create the following data.frame:

```
f <- c("a",2,3,8,7)
g <- c("b",4,1,8,14)
h <- c("abc",7,3,1,4)
i <- c("a",2,3,8,4)
df <- data.frame(f,g,h,i)
```

How can I delete columns `g` and `h` by asking R to delete those columns that *don’t* have “a” in the first row (in the example, keeping `f` and `i` only)?

Comment: `df[grepl("^a$", unlist(df[1, ]))]`? Your question is not really clear.

Comment: I'm sorry, if the first row is *exactly* "a" delete. Otherwise, keep.

Comment: @AnandaMahto  Okay, thanks, then I will edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `grep` to select the columns based on the first row value.  We `unlist` the columns after subsetting the first row, use the pattern as `"a"` that follows the start of the string (`^`) followed by the end of the string (`^$`), i.e there is only a single character in the string and it is `"a"`.  Use the logical index to subset the columns.

```
 df[grepl('^a$', unlist(df[1,]))]
```

NOTE: Inspired from @Ananda Mahto's comments.

Comment: @AnandaMahto  Thanks for that

Answer (score 0):

If you are checking for exactly "a" , then you can just use `==`

```
df[,df[1,] == "a"]
```